# Problem with deleting a CMP file of a Lightning Component

Tags: apex, salesforce-lightning

I have a lightning component that I want to delete, but I am encountering an error when deleting the .cmp file.
The problem is caused due to an implemented Interface : `forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes`

I made sure the component is not used anywhere, including community builder.
I tried to remove the above interface. when I encounter the error while saving :

```
Error:
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION
Failed to save [ComponentName.cmp]: null: Source
```

Also I encounter an error while attempting to delete the component using File | Delete
Entity is deleted